# Как совместить PHP и проценты? (Новая задача)

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста решить маленькую задачу с **процентами** + PHP :)

```
<?php

  $x = 100; // переменной "Х" присвоено число 100

  $y = $x - 10%; // переменной "Y" присвоено задачу, из числа 100 вычесть 10%

  echo $y;    // Вывод результата

?>
```

Если все было так легко то переменной "Y" было присвоено число 90, но в браузере выдает ошибку :( Я так понимаю, что задачу я написал неверно. Помогите, пожалуйста, и покажите, как верно записывать задачи с процентами в PHP коде.

Заранее благодарен. AronTito

Усложню задачу Эйнштейны

```
<?php

$X = 1536.56;    
$Z = $X - 11.5%;    
echo $Z // каков будет результат ???

?>
```

Comment: лол) а надо было всего-то подумать)

Comment: Вы издеваетесь что ли?

    $Z = $X * (100 - 11.5)*0.01;

Comment: Возьмите общий случай с переменной под проценты :)

Answer (score 2):

Вроде-жеж просто:

```
<?php
  $x = 100;
  $y = $x * ( 100 - 10 ) / 100; //Из 100%  вычитаем 10%
  //делим на 100 для приведения к нормальной форме
  //Либо кратко:
  $y = 0.9 * $x;
  echo $y;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Учите матчасть, причем даже не php, а матан 5-го класса

```
$x = 100; // переменной "Х" присвоено число 100
$y = $x * 0.9; // или, если интересно, $x * (100-10)*0.01 или $x - $x*(10)*0.01
```

Comment: матан 5-го класса - именно его, причем основательно :D

Comment: *весь чай пролил на брюки*

Answer (score 1):

Процент (по определению) - сотая часть. Процентов в пхп как таковых нет. Знак `%` служит для других целей.

Всегда, когда вы работаете с процентами (отнимаете как в вашем случае) - работайте с сотыми частями (долями) чисел.

Если вам надо отнять 10 процентов, то это всего лишь означает, что вам надо отнять 10 сотых частей. 10 раз по 1/100. Икс в вашем вопросе выступает в роли исходного числа. А его процент - сотая его часть, `x/100`. 10 процентов от икса - десять таких долей `(x/100) * 10`.

Таким образом запись вида `y = x - 10%` превращается в:

```
y = x - ((x / 100) * 10)
```

Сколько процентов хотите отнять (или прибавить или сделать что угодно), столько и впишите в конце выражения.

Answer (score 0):

Да просто всё!

Вычитаем 10% из 100:

```
<?php
  $x = 100;
  $y = $x * 0.9;
  echo $y;
?>
```

Ответ = 90

Вычитаем 11.5% из 1536.56:

```
<?php
  $x = 1536.56;
  $y = $x * 0.885;
  echo $y;
?>
```

Ответ = 1359.8556

Answer (score 0):

Думаю будет полезно брать переменную, в процентах и вычислять её.

```
<?
    $CAS = 1536.56;//вычисляемое число
    $procent = 11.5;//Или введите своё число процентов.

    echo($CAS-($CAS/100*$procent));
?>
```